# Mousewheel plugin is not working in FancyBox 2

Tags: jquery, firefox, ubuntu, fancybox, mousewheel

I've added both [FancyBox 2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) and [Mousewheel](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel/) plugin to my project as well as jQuery using Bower.

For some reason FancyBox is not reacting to mousewheel events at all.

There is no errors in the console, but I can confirm that Mousewheel plugin is working by itself (I can add events manually and listeners are fired for them).

What could be the problem?

---

#### Software versions

- jQuery — `2.1.3`
- Mousewheel — `3.1.12`
- Fancybox 2 — `2.1.5`
- Mozilla Firefox — `35.0.1` *for Ubuntu Linux*

Comment: It's very difficult to diagnose a problem while there isn't any apparent error and fancybox and mousewheel work just fine together  http://jsfiddle.net/jjnvdjt4/  (of course you have to hover the images to navigate with the mousewheel) ...have you tried installing them manually instead of using bower? it may give you a clue about what's going on

Comment: @JFK , thank you for your answer! I will try to re-create the situation using Plunker, if time permits = )